# CSS list styling - how to reduce the distance between parent and children of the previous parent?

Tags: css, list, styles

See the menu on the left: http://goo.gl/gV6B8D

I want to reduce or remove the ugly gap between the parent items and the children of the previous parent.
(I'll differentiate parent from children using different styling, so the parent-child structure is needed,
and that's how wordpress generates menus anyway).

How to do this?

CSS code:

```
.advanced-sidebar-menu ul {
    background-color : #EDEDED;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: ##EDEDED;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul li {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.advanced-sidebar-menu ul li a:hover { background: white; }

.widget-area .child-sidebar-menu, .widget-area .child-sidebar-menu li { padding : 0; margin : 0 0 15px 0; }
.widget-area .child-sidebar-menu li li { margin-bottom : 0; }
.widget-area .child-sidebar-menu a { margin : 0; }

.child-sidebar-menu * {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.child-sidebar-menu > li a {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}

.child-sidebar-menu li li a {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your css code.

Comment: "See the menu on the left" - since you've linked to an external website which is subject to change, and provided no HTML or screenshot, there is very little about this problem that can be of use to anyone in the future. It is useful to only you, whilst SO questions are supposed to be a source of knowledge for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the margin on this line:

> .widget-area .child-sidebar-menu, .widget-area .child-sidebar-menu li { padding : 0; margin : 0 0 15px 0; }

Just set it to margin: 0px; 
That should fix your menu issue.